# Material Icons doesn't seem to work inside Template (Web Components)

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, mdc-components

I was trying to use the Material Components for Web in my page([LINK](https://codepen.io/rleo2joseph/pen/KKKzeqY?editors=1010)).

Able to create a FAB using MDC and you can find them in here [CODE-PEN][2]

But when I try to do the same inside the Template and Custom Elements(Web Component), it doesn't seem to be working [LINK](https://codepen.io/rleo2joseph/pen/KKKzeqY?editors=1010)

I get the proper CSS for the FAB but the icon is not displaying. Can anyone help me with this?

`MDC LINK`[1](https://codepen.io/rleo2joseph/pen/KKKzeqY?editors=1010): https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-fab

`WORKING` [2]: https://codepen.io/rleo2joseph/pen/GRRZGRv

`NOT WORKING` [3]: https://codepen.io/rleo2joseph/pen/KKKzeqY?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your import order (of css) is incorrect... I've tried this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

And it worked just fine... (maybe the `material-components-web` overrides some material icons definitions)

Anyhow - I do hope that you used your css links inside a component to demonstration purposes only and that your css deceleration in original code is placed at the head section of your page (or any other css bootstrapper in that matter)

---

**UPDATE:**

Please include Material Icons in your pen configurations (css section), like this:

[image]

Again, I do hope that in your project you defined the links (and their order) as I already noted in my original answer... including `link` element inside a component is truly not recommended (importing multiple components will result in multiple unnecessary imports)

Comment: No. I tried that too. It doesn't seem to be working